# How to install cocos2d-objc-3.5?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I dowanloads the zip from github,but i can't find file to install(like install-templates.sh ).Here is the link:https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc

I runed the cocos2d.xcodeproj and cocos2d-test.xcodeproj in Xcode,but nothing happend...

Then i download the CCProjectGenerator and run it in Xcode.like this:

[image]
It only created a new file which can't run...So what share i do next?
//My English is poor..Sorry

Comment: i am also facing same issue. if you find any solution update here.